# Using Prototype methods for Controllers

Tags: angularjs, prototype, angularjs-controller

I have joined a team where we are using AngularJS. I have good amount of experience in Javascript however have just started on AnjularJS. We are following John Papa's guideline as a general approach. We are using Controller as syntax everywhere. As part of the team discussion one point was raised in the context of keeping Controllers thin. And some of the members are of the view that all the methods should be defined as part of Controller's prototype instead of instance methods(attached to this).

I searched a lot but i didn't get any particular advantage/disadvantage of using this approach over instance methods other than 
1) of having shared memory for the functions. 
2) Inheritance can be used to share/reuse functionality in a controller hierarchy(I doubt if this is a common scenario in AngularJS controllers and if having hierarchy of controllers is good idea.)

What we have decided is 
1) all methods should be added to prototype of controller
2) dependencies injected should be exposed by attaching them to "this" variable so that they are available to proptotype methods.

Would like to know any clear advantages and disadvantages from AngularJS perspective.

I have received a concrete answer from John Papa whose guideline we follow and it matches with what I was thinking.
            https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/issues/524

However I would still like any other reasons with advantage/disadvantage. This is because the main issues here is keeping the controller(specifically controller constructor function) thin. Without moving methods to prototype is there generic ways to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

> of having shared memory for the functions

Why do you want to share functions ? I do not see any advantage.

> This is because the main issues here is keeping the controller(specifically controller constructor function) thin.

If this is the problem, instead of thinking that shared object functions, will solve this.Try to refactor you controllers : as their name tells, they must have a simple task => Control. **They do not do the stuff, they just ask.**

- Extract logic in services.
- Do not manipulate dom in controllers, use directives (are you injecting $document ?).
- Extract simple formatting/presentation manipulations in filters.

Comment: I think we are already doing things listed down here including moving logic into services. but I cannot move manipulation of model which i do once i receive response from service into service itself I will have to do that in controller. only business logic which will give me data snapshot needed to be represented in view will go into services and we are already doing that. Sharing functions does not mean sharing functionality across controllers it means sharing functions across multiple instances of the controller which is usually case with directive controllers but not in view controller,